# Using JDeveloper 12c to consume restful webservice returning JSON

Tags: json, rest, jsf, jdeveloper

I want to consume a restful web-service which is returning JSON, in such a way that creating its DataControl, which will help me in creating JSF pages on drag and drop.

I am using JDeveloper 12.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create/code Java classes that talk to the JSON backend.
Then you can expose those classes as data controls that you'll be able to bind to your JSF pages.

Comment: how java class can talk to json at backend ?? some code or link ?

Comment: @asif_ali0869: any java rest tutorial with test clients will show you... make google your friend (or any other searchengine of your liking)